# Frame with 50 png in iPhone

Tags: iphone, frame, render, imagenamed

I have a ViewController with 16 buttons. Each button loads a popover that show 50 frames renders in moving.

What is the best form to do it?

I know that `imageWithName` is bad because it load all images in cache, and for this reason im doing it with:

```
myAnimatedView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0000",nombrePieza]ofType:@"png"]],
                                [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0001",nombrePieza]ofType:@"png"]],
                                [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0002",nombrePieza]ofType:@"png"]],
    ...
    ...
    ...                         [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0050",nombrePieza]ofType:@"png"]],nil];
```

But when i load about 10 times the popover with differents frames, i have a leak of memory only on my device, but not in the simulator.

For this reason, i want know which is the best form to do it?

With a video? or with `CAAnimation`?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a timer in this case, not to have memory problems

```
...
page = 1;
imageAnim = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[[self view] addSubview:imageAnim];
tim = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(avv) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
...

- (void)avv {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SplashAnimation %03d", page] ofType:@"png"]];
    [imageAnim setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [imageAnim setImage:img];
    page++;
    if(page > maxNumberFrame) {
       [tim invalidate];
    }
}
```

This is an example to get ideas

Answer (score 0):

`imageNamed` does not cause a leak in itself (although some previous discussions suggest it may have had bugs in pre iOS 4).

However, `imageNamed` will cache your images so that you don't load them for every instance if the image that you show. In your case, if you load the animation 10 times, I think you will see that each image gets loaded only once. Your current solution will force your images to be loaded every time.

Most importantly, the `imageNamed`method will transparantly handle the Retina version of the images, which you would have to do manually otherwise.

From the documentation:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend. I dont load the same 50 images... Each button have 50 differents images, and my leak is doing when i load 10 times with differents images... Some solution?